# Problemas con git al actualizar mi SO

Tags: git, github, consola

Hace poco actualice mi sistema operativo a Sierra y cuando quise utilizar la aplicación de githubdesktop me arrojo el siguiente error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probando en la línea de comandos cada vez que me quiero realizar algún pull me solicita el password de mi llave

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrian ayudarme a resolver este problema.

De antemano Gracia.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas

creo que se trata de un problema de tu ssh id_rsa, tal y como muestra el mensaje de error. Supongo que al actualizar la versión de SO, hayas perdido el fichero `~/.ssh/id_rsa` 
¿Podrías comprobar si tienes ese fichero en el path del usuario?
En caso de que no lo tengas, podrías generar un nuevo:

```
ssh-keygen -p
```

Posteriormente, se habrá creado un archivo id_rsa, cuyo contenido debes setear en GitHub Desktop. No conozco muy bien el menú de Git Hub desktop, ya que solo he trabajado con gerrit, pero seguro que hay alguna opción en la configuración de tu usuario donde te permita añadir claves y poder copiar el contenido de ese archivo id_rsa.

Una vez hayas hecho eso, si pruebas a trabajar con tu repositorio git, debería funcionarte y no volver a aparecer ese mensaje de error.

Un saludo